# Read access denied to files on Windows with READ permissions defined in Java

Tags: java, windows, file-permissions, user-permissions

Using Java's [ACL File Attribute API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/package-summary.html), I create a file for which only the current user has only read and delete permission ([specifically](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclEntryPermission.html) `READ_DATA`, `READ_ATTRIBUTES`, `READ_NAMED_ATTRS`, `READ_ACL`, and `DELETE`). It looks like the permissions "take":

[image: basic-security-settings]

[image: security-settings]

However, when I try to actually read the file, it fails, "Access is denied". (I've tried opening it notepad, using "cat" from git for Windows bash, and opening a FileInputStream from Java.)

Can anyone explain why this fails? Is there anyway to debug the authorization process?

I'm basically trying to generate files with something like permissions `-r--------` on a POSIX filesystem, files that are intended to be unusually private (encrypted cryptographic keys, which should be accessible only to the user), and are not intended to be modified. Is there something else I ought to be doing? Is there a better way (working from a JVM)?

Comment: At a guess, you might need to include "synchronize" and/or "execute" permission.  If that doesn't work, use Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) to check exactly which access permissions are being requested.  If you still can't work out what's happening, post the output of `icacls myfilename` as well as the details from Process Monitor.